# Winddata Structure and Interpolation

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I'm using QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas)

I have hourly Data (of a whole year) of 11 Wind Measuring Points in an area.

How would i best structure my Data (8760 hours for a whole year) for 11 measuring points in order to have the possibilty to interpolate within the points?

Or can anyone perhaps name some scientfic papers i could consult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend you doing this in a 'generic' GIS.  You are much better advised to use software specifically designed to model windflow over terrains as this is a non-trivial task.  I'm not saying you can't do it in QGIS, but without a fluid dynamics module, your interpolation will be naive at best and fail to account for turbulence, wind shear, surface roughness canyon effects etc etc.

Suitable software includes [WAsP](http://www.wasp.dk/) and windfarm software such as [WindFarm](http://www.resoft.co.uk/), [WindPro](http://www.emd.dk/windpro/) and [WindFarmer](https://www.dnvgl.com/services/windfarmer-3766) (other packages exist).  If you want something free you can try the community edition of [OpenWind](http://software.awstruepower.com/openwind/).

The short answer to your question is, when using one of these packages, I'd structure the data using the hourly data for each of the eleven points (i.e. associate the relevant data with the relevant point).  If you want more information on this subject then the documentatino of any of these packages will help you and point you to more scientific papers too.